# Why the abbreviation "maitre d'"?

Tags: foreign-phrases

I have often seen the expression *maitre d'* in English texts.
It obviously comes from the French *maître d'hôtel*, meaning more or less head waiter.
I can understand that the *î* in *maître* would be transformed into *i* in English texts for lack of the appropriate diacritic, but the transformation of *d'hôtel*  into the strangely dangling *d'* baffles me.
Also: I have the vague feeling,  that the expression *maitre d'* is rather modern in the sense that I see it on the Internet and not in the books I read (most of which, admittedly, were written several decades ago).
Could some anglophone enlighten a puzzled Frenchman?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but as a speaker of British English, I find this American expression just as strange as your do.

Comment: @Colin, thanks for your unexpected (and, in a way, comforting !) comment.

Comment: What is this modern usage of *maître d'*? I have only seen it in *maître d'hôtel*.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey Interesting. I don’t recall ever seeing _maître d’hôtel_ used in English literature—it’s always just been _maitre d’_ or _maître d’_.

Comment: It's no more odd than is the French abbreviation (slang) [*système D*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_D).

Comment: A trendy French restaurant in NYC should serve up some *hors d's*.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that it is simple an abbreviation which was used from 1942 probably when he term was used mainly to refer to the manager of a dining room:

> - By the late 19th century, the term was being used to refer to a hotel manager; in the 20th century, ***it came to mean the manager of a hotel dining room and eventually a headwaiter.***

***[Maitre d'hotel](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=maitre%20d%27hotel&allowed_in_frame=0):***

> - 1530s, "head domestic," from French maître d'hôtel, literally "house-master," from Old French maistre "master; skilled worker, educator" (12c.).  ***Sense of "hotel manager, manager of a dining room" is from 1890.*** - ***Shortened form maître d' is attested from 1942***;

***[Plural of maitre d'](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2007/01/whats-the-plural-of-maitre-d.html):***

> - When a compound word is split into parts, with or without hyphens (like mother-in-law or attorney general), the plural ending traditionally goes on the most important part (mothers-in-law or attorneys general).
> - ***But maitre d’ is a special case. The plural of the full version is maîtres d’hôtel, as one would expect, but the plural of the shortened form is maitre d’s***, according to The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language.

Note that:

> - the full version has French accents, but the shorter one doesn’t. Also, the last syllable of the abbreviated version is pronounced DEEZ.

Comment: And the first syllable is pronounced MATE.

Comment: @John. That's interesting: I had no idea that the *r* wasn't pronounced. Nor that one pronounced the *a* as in *mate*, rather than as in *met*.

Comment: Only the first syllable is MATE. The unstressed /ər/ goes between the two stressed syllables, thus: /'metər'di/. The stressed English vowels are both tense, however; /e/ is tense [e:], not lax [ɛ] like the French word _maître_ /mɛtʀ̥/.

Comment: I'm familiar with two pronunciations: the slangier or less educated  /'meɪtə'di/ and a more "correct" attempt /'meɪtrə'di/.

Comment: Depends on whom you're trying to impress. The maitre d' or an actual French speaker.

Comment: Presumably when the term came to apply specifically to a worker at a restaurant, keeping "hotel" in the title wouldn't make a lot of sense (also "hôtel" in French has a different, wider meaning than in English). Also worth noting that "chef" comes from the French "chef de cuisine" (chief of the kitchen, but again "cuisine" means something different in English). I guess the real question is why keep the "d'" (maybe because "maitre" sounds too much like "mater=mother").